# numpy lstsq -- memory and run-time performance

Tags: performance, memory, numpy, linear-algebra

I need to solve (in the least-squares sense) a large set (50,000) of linear systems. Each such "system" is `Ax=B`, with `A` being an N-by-K matrix, `x` being an k-by-1 vector, and B (obviously) being an N-by-1 vector. (N in my case is 50,000, and K is ~10).

numpy.linalg.lstsq seems like the obvious choice, but since the documentation contains no implementation details, I am wondering about the memory and run-time performance:

What are the run-time performance and memory requirements of lstsq?

1. Will it compute the A, A^T, multiply them, and take the inverse, or will it compute A's pseudo-inverse directly?
2. Is there a way to directly compute each X[i] of the result, thus saving on memory? Will it use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) describes the result as including the singular values and the rank; a strong hint that it is using SVD.

A quick test on my laptop shows the memory not going up at all (as reported by System Monitor) after the allocation of the arrays A and B.

```
In [7]: A = np.random.randn(100000, 10)

In [8]: B = np.random.randn(100000)

In [9]: np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)
Out[9]: 
(array([ 0.00240061,  0.0017896 ,  0.00619928,  0.00010278, -0.00411501,
         0.00028532,  0.0003893 , -0.00042893,  0.00178326, -0.00444068]),
 array([ 99695.18278372]),
 10,
 array([ 318.37776275,  318.16578799,  317.82872616,  317.21981114,
         316.80987468,  315.63798002,  315.46574698,  314.73120345,
         313.99948001,  313.61503118]))
```

Comment: I was just going to write something similar, but you beat me to it and deserve my +1. In experiments I ran, my memory consumption did not increase one bit, even for way larger inputs. I can't explain it, and would be glad if someone did. The running time seems to be linear in N (if I keep k constant). I measured this with tens of input sizes. Finally, looking at the source code for linalg.py it seems like it uses lapack's dgelsd (at least on my machine and the way I have it installed), which according to the docs uses SVD. How does one compute the SVD in linear time and with zero memory? :-)

Comment: They have a formula for the workspace required here: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgelsd.f